# Fedora 30: GTK fails to load appmenu-gtk-module

Tags: qt, menu, gtk, fedora

I am learning to program in Python and Rust. On different versions of Ubuntu these programs compiled and ran perfectly. Now that I have a dedicated Fedora 30 KDE system, every time I try and build a program, I get a warning: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

I have tried looking this up and have re/installed anything GTK on my system. The programs otherwise function well, but no menus are drawn. I was also trying things in GNOME and hit the same thing.

I am also using QT. Those programs also build and run fine, but again, no menu.

I'm going bonkers with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The appmenu-gtk module is not packaged on Fedora. (GNOME doesn't support them anyway.)

The real questions are:

Why is it configured to load? Did you copy or share GTK config files from an Ubuntu system? You should remove this module from your settings.

Even with improper configs I don't believe this should result in menus not appearing. It should just fail to load and work as normal. How is your application using menus?

Comment: Everything works fine under GNOME and cinnamon spins, but does this in KDE Fusion only. I'm just going back to using GNOME and all is well. A shame; I find I like KDE.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got so fed up with getting this error that I went full nerd-diagnosis, and ran this command to find out which file contained the errant reference to the `appmenu-gtk` (the package that would provide this is not installable on my system either).

(Replace "`dolphin`" with the command that is giving you the error.)

```
strace -e openat,access dolphin 2>&1 |grep -v ENOENT |awk '/appmenu-gtk/ {exit} !/appmenu-gtk/ {print}'|cut -d '"' -f2 |sort|uniq|xargs grep appmenu-gtk 2>/dev/null
```

This will then give you a list of files which contain the line `appmenu-gtk`, and in my case it was `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. From there I just commented it out, and that gets rid of the error message (not sure if this will fix your problem of not having any menus, but you might just be able to edit that line to fix it in another way if commenting it out doesn't work).